# Javascript JSON loop - how to access only specific attribute

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to read the data from this URL:

https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings?_sorted&_limit=3

The URL returns:

```
{
   "@context":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/meta/context.jsonld",
   "meta":{
      "publisher":"Environment Agency",
      "licence":"http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/3/",
      "documentation":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/doc/reference",
      "version":"0.9",
      "comment":"Status: Beta service",
      "hasFormat":[
         "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings.csv?_sorted&_limit=3",
         "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings.rdf?_sorted&_limit=3",
         "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings.ttl?_sorted&_limit=3",
         "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings.html?_sorted&_limit=3"
      ],
      "limit":3
   },
   "items":[
      {
         "@id":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/data/readings/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/2024-02-15T12-15-00Z",
         "dateTime":"2024-02-15T12:15:00Z",
         "measure":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m",
         "value":1.043
      },
      {
         "@id":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/data/readings/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/2024-02-15T12-00-00Z",
         "dateTime":"2024-02-15T12:00:00Z",
         "measure":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m",
         "value":1.05
      },
      {
         "@id":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/data/readings/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/2024-02-15T11-45-00Z",
         "dateTime":"2024-02-15T11:45:00Z",
         "measure":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m",
         "value":1.058
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using this to loop through the records from the `items` section:

```js
let url = "https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings?_sorted&_limit=3";

var request;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

request.open('GET', url);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((request.status === 200) && (request.readyState === 4)) {
        var info = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var output = "";
        for (var i = 0; i <= info.items.length-1; i++) {
            for(var key in info.items[i]) {
                console.log(info.items[i]['value']);
            }
        }
    }
}

request.send();
```

The following is written to the console:

```
1.043
1.043
1.043
1.043
1.05
1.05
1.05
1.05
1.058
1.058
1.058
1.058
```

I presume that's because each record in the `item` contains 4 elements / attributes (sorry I don't know the correct term to use) - for example:

```
"@id":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/data/readings/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/2024-02-15T12-00-00Z",
"dateTime":"2024-02-15T12:00:00Z",
"measure":"http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m",
"value":1.05
```

How could I change the loop so that only 3 records are returned, accessing the `value` attribute only?

I would prefer to use vanilla JS rather than jQuery.

Sorry for not knowing the answer, I will probably be downvoted for that. I have spent all morning trying to work it out but I have not been able to.

Comment: Get rid of the superfluous inner `for` loop!?

Comment: `info.items.forEach(row => console.log(row.value))`

Comment: OT - While you're at it. Take a look at the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let url = "https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/681210-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings?_sorted&_limit=3";

var request;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

request.open('GET', url);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((request.status === 200) && (request.readyState === 4)) {
        var info = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var output = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < info.items.length; i++) {
            console.log(info.items[i].value);
        }
    }
}

request.send();
```

From the above modified code :

- We directly access the "value" attribute of each item using info.items[i].value.
- We no longer need the inner loop (for (var key in info.items[i])) because we're only interested in the "value" attribute.
- We iterate over the info.items array using for (var i = 0; i < info.items.length; i++) to ensure that only three records are logged to the console.